# Python raw_input() Syntax Error

Tags: python

Whenever I run this piece of code, it keeps pointing to the "t" in `raw_input()` and saying `SyntaxError: invalid syntax.` Did I do something wrong?

```
if key == True:
                when raw_input().lower() = "get":
                print "Sorry, there is nothing more to get here."
```

Comment: There's no keyword `when`; you wanted `if`. Also, the indentation of `print` is off, it must be indented relative to the `if` (the one which is now "when").

Comment: And it should be '==' instead of '='

Comment: `when` is an experimental Perl keyword, not Python.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is

```
if key == True:
    if raw_input().lower() == "get":
        print "Sorry, there is nothing more to get here."
```

There is no keyword when

Comment: @cdarke: When I read your comment at first I thought you meant "There is no keyword `if key:`". I eventually figured out what you meant.

Comment: @RoryDaulton:  oops, sorry.

Comment: @cdarke: No need to apologize. I was pointing out my weakness, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean, but you are writing some sort of pseudo-code.  Try this:

```
if key:
    while True:
        reply = raw_input().lower()
        if reply == "get":
            print "Sorry, there is nothing more to get here."
            break
        # else ...
```

I dispensed with the `== True`, that's just a personal preference, nothing wrong with using it if you prefer.

I stored the returned string entered by the user into `reply`, since presumably you will be processing the user's reply.  I also put this in a loop, which you imply by using the word `when` rather than `if`.  `break` exits the loop immediately.